# C++ Traits and Policies

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on an example from "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide
By David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis" and changed a little bit of the code below. I can't understand why it doesn't compile. Any help? (error messages below)

```
    // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <deque>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class AccumulationTraits;

template<>
class AccumulationTraits<int>{
    public:
        typedef long Ac;
        static Ac zero(){
            return 0;
        }
};

template<>
class AccumulationTraits<float>{
    public:
        typedef double Ac;
        static Ac zero(){
            return 0;
        }
};

template<typename T,typename Trait=AccumulationTraits<T>>
class SumPolicy{
    public:
        static typename Trait::Ac accumulate(typename Trait::Ac& total ,const T& beg){
            return total+=beg;
        }
};

template<typename T, typename Trait=AccumulationTraits<T>>
class MultPoliciy{
    public:
        static typename Trait::Ac accumulate(typename Trait::Ac& total, const T& beg){
            return total*=beg;
        }
};


template<typename T, template<typename, typename> class Policy=SumPolicy, typename Traits=AccumulationTraits<T>>
class Accum{
    public:
         static typename Traits::Ac accum(const T* beg, const T* end){
             typename Traits::Ac total=Traits::zero();
             while(beg!=end){
                 Policy<T>::accumulate(total, *beg);
                 ++beg;
             }
             return total;
         }
};


template<typename T, template<typename, typename> class Policy=SumPolicy>
inline typename AccumulationTraits<T>::Ac accum(const T* beg, const T* end){
    return Accum<T, Policy>::accum(beg, end);
}

template<typename T, template<typename> class AccumulationTraits,  template <typename, typename> class Policy=SumPolicy>
inline typename AccumulationTraits<T>::Ac accum(const T* beg, const T* end){
    return Accum<T, Policy, AccumulationTraits>::accum(beg,end);
}

int main()
{
    int num[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << "The average is : " << accum<int, MultPoliciy>(&num[0], &num[5]) << std::endl;
}
```

Error message is:

```
  source_file.cpp(53): error C2976: 'MultPoliciy': too few template arguments
source_file.cpp(39): note: see declaration of 'MultPoliciy'
source_file.cpp(50): note: while compiling class template member function 'AccumulationTraits<int>::Ac Accum<T,Policy,AccumulationTraits<int>>::accum(const T *,const T *)'
        with
        [
            T=int,
            Policy=MultPoliciy
        ]
source_file.cpp(63): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'AccumulationTraits<int>::Ac Accum<T,Policy,AccumulationTraits<int>>::accum(const T *,const T *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int,
            Policy=MultPoliciy
        ]
source_file.cpp(63): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Accum<T,Policy,AccumulationTraits<int>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int,
            Policy=MultPoliciy
        ]
source_file.cpp(74): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'AccumulationTraits<int>::Ac accum<int,MultPoliciy>(const T *,const T *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
source_file.cpp(53): error C2955: 'MultPoliciy': use of class template requires template argument list
source_file.cpp(39): note: see declaration of 'MultPoliciy'
source_file.cpp(53): error C2670: 'MultPoliciy<T,Trait>::accumulate': the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'AccumulationTraits<int>::Ac'
```

Comment: `Policy` template template parameter requires two arguments; no defaults are specified. You are trying to instantiate it with one, as in `Policy<T>`. The fact that it happens to be bound to a class template that does have a default for one of its arguments is irrelevant. Make it `Policy<T, Traits>::accumulate(total, *beg);`

Comment: so we can't have a template parameter that has default template parameter itself? or, how do you pass a template parameter that has default template parameters as i'm trying to do with `Policy` in `Accum`?

Comment: Indeed it works for `Policy<T, Traits>::accumulate(total, *beg);` but i don't understand why it doesn't for `Policy<T>::accumulate(total, *beg);`. I thought that the second template parameter for `Policy` can be deduced from the first one as it suggests when declaring `template<typename T,typename Trait=AccumulationTraits<T>>
class SumPolicy`

Comment: `so we can't have a template parameter that has default template parameter itself?` You can: `template <template <typename Param=Default> class TemplateParameter> class C {};` . Though in your code, it's not clear why you would want that: it seems that you would *want* to use `Traits` parameter as an argument for `Policy` - otherwise, why have `Traits` at all?